# Making if null then ignore else date range (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I want to make an if statement to not filter out those which has `NULL` `idBillingTransaction`

so something like, if idBillingTransaction is not null then daterange else, there should be no filter for the date range in `idBillingTransactions` (because it has nulls)

Here is the code

```
select * 
from subscription cs
  LEFT JOIN
  billing_transaction bt
    ON CONVERT(cs.msisdn USING latin1) = bt.msisdn 

    where 
      bt.idBillingTransaction
      BETWEEN (SELECT idBillingTransaction
               FROM transaction_ids
               WHERE dt = '2017-03-31')
      AND (SELECT idBillingTransaction
           FROM transaction_ids
           WHERE dt = '2017-04-30')
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data, your current output, and then explain what about your current output you want to change?

Comment: The dataset is huge and needs more inner joins to show the problem. i just need avoid nulls being filter out

Comment: So you want to retain all `NULL` id billing transaction records?  Is that right?

Comment: right...........

Comment: Thanks for marking me correct, but if you still have problems related to this question feel free to come back and drop a note.  Or, you could open a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be able to get what you want just by modifying the `WHERE` clause to not remove `NULL` id billing transactions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM subscription cs
LEFT JOIN billing_transaction bt
    ON CONVERT(cs.msisdn USING latin1) = bt.msisdn 
LEFT JOIN transaction_ids t
    ON bt.idBillingTransaction = t.idBillingTransaction AND
       t.dt BETWEEN '2017-03-31' AND '2017-04-30'
```

I also removed the two subqueries in the `WHERE` clause, because I don't think that they are necessary.  Instead, it would be much cleaner to just do another join to the `transaction_ids` table on the id billing transaction, and then compare a range of dates.

Comment: will get back to u on this in a while. seems logical yea!!

Comment: Can this where clause be a part of left join?

Comment: Yes, I think it can, good suggestion.  And I also think this takes care of the `NULL` problem you were having.  Because we're doing a `LEFT JOIN`, those `NULL` transaction id records should still be present, they just wouldn't have any data from the `transaction_ids` table.

Comment: Can you modify it again without the left join for transaction_ids. It has other complications. I would just like to have the previous version in the left join condition

Comment: Can the left join has OR condition in it?

Comment: Yes, of course it can.  You should work on your question such that it has a minimal example.  If I revert to the previous version, it would be bad SQL.  Really, if your actual query is using subqueries like that, then it probably can be improved.

Comment: I have an option to completely remove the date range in billing and just left join over msisdn. Would it effect the performance? billingtransactions table is huge

Comment: In other words, does the date range restriction improves or reduce the performance?

Comment: If there is an index on the `transaction_ids.dt` column, then the `WHERE` clause should improve performance, because then MySQL would "know" roughly where to go to get the records eligible for the join.